# How to display android button text without dotted capital letter "I"?

Tags: java, android, uppercase

So i'm aware that android automatically sets button text characters to allCaps. However, my problem is that when i use lower case character "i" in a button text, it displays capital I letter with a dot. (it might be since i test the app on a phone that is set to turkish language).

How can i display capital I letter without a dot in a button text, as it is in the english language, no matter what language the phone is being used with?

Comment: Attach screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `android:textAllCaps="true"` is set (it is by default on Buttons), the system will essentially call `yourText.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())` on whatever text you set to the view. To work around this, set `textAllCaps` to false, and then uppercase it using `yourString.toUpperCase(Locale.US)`.